# iOS Strong password problem when I start typing the password field

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, passwords

I have created a register page in iOS which has a password and another confirm password field. Both has a content type password, keyboard is ASCII enabled. When I start typing the password on simulator's keyboard I get a text written Strong password on both which lets me to write nothing else, But I don't get any such error when I type on my laptop's keyboard. I have attached the screenshot.

[Strong password problem in iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRtJd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this error is still here. It comes with "Secure Text Entry" by default.

But, you can change your UITextField to the "One Time Code" and error will be gone.

For example:

```
Swift

yourTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

Comment: This is hack, it breaks password managers and autofill functionality in other cases.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Setting.

[image]

Click on Password

[image]

Give any password and press enter.

[image]

And off AutofillPassword

[image]

Comment: For people getting this error, you can just do the above steps again. Error will go away.

Comment: yes error will go, try it.

Comment: So what if it goes away?  Users want autofill to work and to not screw them is strong password is not used.